# NSFetchedResultsController sort using child attribute

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I have one-to-many parent-child entity Book <->> Borrow

Book

- name
- borrows (relation)

Borrow

- borrowDate
- note
- book (relation)

and I want to sort Book entity in `NSFetchedResultsController` using max `NSDate` of child entity to show most recently borrowed book.

How can I do this ? I tried using my own method something like this using Category on Book

```
- (NSArray *)borrowSortedByborrowedDate
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByCreatedDate = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"borrowDate" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [self.histories sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByCreatedDate]];
    return sortedArray;
}

- (NSDate *)recentBorrowDate
{
    Borrow *borrow = [[self borrowSortedByborrowedDate] objectAtIndex:0];
    return borrow.borrowDate;
}
```

and put it in `sortDescriptor`

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"recentBorrowDate" ascending:YES];
```

but it didn't work.

**Here is my fetched request (Didn't work)**

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"recentBorrowDate" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

My expected result is

- Book name1 (borrowDate today)
- Book name2 (borrowDate yesterday)
- Book name3 (borrowDate many days ago)

Comment: Could you provide the fetch request? Then are you perform the request against `Book`? Finally, what is `History` and what about *note*? Thanks.

Comment: Yes fetch request perform against Book with no predicate. I want to sort it using NSDate from most recently borrowed book. Note is one property of borrow.

Comment: Could you provide the fetch request you are using? Do you want to order books from the most recent date to the last one? Thank you.

Comment: I added my fetch request on the post, but it didn't work.

Comment: @art I am currently trying to figure out how to do the exact same thing

Comment: Do you need to calculate the max borrow date for each book or the max among all?

Comment: I want to sort Book by date of its most recently Borrow(max borrowDate). That would be max borrow date for each book.

Comment: I added an edit. Check memory management if you don't use ARC. Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: Your edited version is just a way to find max Borrow by borrowDate which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue and this is my current workaround to achieve the desired output. (maybe this is the only way, but I am still looking...)

When creating a new Borrow just update the book.lastBorrowDate property at the same time.

```
// Create new Borrow and set Book
Borrow *newBorrow = (Borrow *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Borrow" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
newBorrow.book = theBook;
newBorrow.borrowDate = [NSDate date];
newBorrow.note = theNote;

// Now also update our book's lastBorrowDate tracking property
theBook.lastBorrowDate = [NSDate date];

// Save all our changes
NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    // Something went horribly wrong...
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error: %@, %@, %@", error, [error userInfo],[error localizedDescription]);
    abort(); // Fail
}
```

Now when pulling them out later it's easy...

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastBorrowDate" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: Yes this is the same way I tried while waiting to see if there is a better solution, if nothing better I have to go with this solution too :( .It is a bit hassle because you have to maintain `lastBorrowDate` manually in case you let user edit Borrow entity themselves (like reorder, delete).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the possibility to add `lastBorrowedDate` property to your Books managed object. If you want to make sorts and searches on this field it is necessary to optimize your MOM to get better efficiency. Also you could get the code more simple.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have a similar issue in a similar context. You can check out the post here: [Custom NSSortDescriptor on complex object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182297/custom-nssortdescriptor-on-complex-object/11182443#comment14693272_11182443)

To sum-up, I need to sort using both a child attribute and an entity attribute. The only workaround that was found is to use a custom sort descriptor and applying the filters after. This means you have to perform the fetch, get the fetchResults, then sort them in an array. I'm mostly worried by performance issue with this workaround though. In your case, the custom sort would probably be something like:

```
@interface Book(category) {}
@end
@implementation Book(category) 
- (NSDate*)getMostRecentDate {
  NSDate* mostRecentDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
  for(Borrow* b in [self borrows]) {
    mostRecentDate = [mostRecentDate laterDate:[b borrowDate]];
  }
  return mostRecentDate;
}
@end

@interface SortDescriptor : NSSortDescriptor {}
@end
@implementation SortDescriptor
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone
{
    return [[[self class] alloc] initWithKey:[self key] ascending:[self ascending] selector:[self selector]];
}
- (NSComparisonResult)compareObject:(id)object1 toObject:(id)object2
{
    return [[(Book*)object1 getMostRecentDate] compare:[(Book*)object2 getMostRecentDate]];
}
@end
```

Let me know what you think about this solution. I'm starting tests to decide whether changing the sort to make it simpler or use the NSArray.