# Custom NSSortDescriptor on complex object

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, nssortdescriptor

It's my first post so sorry if I may not respect all the conventions even though I'll try my best. I have always found solutions to my problems on SO before but I'm completely stuck on a rather complex Cocoa problem.

I am trying to achieve a complex sort on a list of CoreData objects. I have a catalog composed of Book objects, which can be part of Saga (first book and its sequels). The simplified structures look like this:

```
@interface Book : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * tomaison; //volume numbering
@property (nonatomic, retain) Saga *fromSaga;

@interface Saga : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
```

I'm trying to perform a query on my CoreData db, on Book:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

and I need a sort in three steps:

1) Sort by book's Genre (not included in the code above because it's not needed), which is performed with:

```
NSSortDescriptor* mainSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"ofGenre.title" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

2) Sort by Saga title if the book is part of a Saga

```
NSSortDescriptor* secondarySort = [[SagaTitleSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"fromSaga" ascending:YES];
```

Where the custom sort descriptor is defined by:

```
#define NULL_OBJECT(a) ((a) == nil || [(a) isEqual:[NSNull null]])
@interface SagaTitleSortDescriptor : NSSortDescriptor {}
@end
@implementation SagaTitleSortDescriptor
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone
{
    return [[[self class] alloc] initWithKey:[self key] ascending:[self ascending] selector:[self selector]];
}
- (NSComparisonResult)compareObject:(id)object1 toObject:(id)object2
{
    if (NULL_OBJECT([object1 valueForKeyPath:[self key]])) {
        if (NULL_OBJECT([object2 valueForKeyPath:[self key]])) 
            return NSOrderedSame;
        return NSOrderedDescending;        
    }
    if (NULL_OBJECT([object2 valueForKeyPath:[self key]])) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return [super compareObject:[(Saga*)object1 title] toObject:[(Saga*)object2 title]];
}
@end
```

3) Sort by Volume Numbering IF it is part of a Saga, otherwise, sort by Book Title. Here is my problem, as I don't know what key to send and what to put in my descriptor (I'm not even sure it's possible).

```
NSSortDescriptor* thirdSort = [[SagaTomaisonOrBookTitleSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
```

So far, I've found that @"self" allows to send the object being queried but it doesn't seem to allow queries of parameters inside the sent object. For reference, there is some code I tried:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareObject:(id)object1 toObject:(id)object2
{
    if (NULL_OBJECT([(Book*)object1 fromSaga]) && NULL_OBJECT([(Book*)object2 fromSaga])) {
        return [super compareObject:[(Book*)object1 title] toObject:[(Book*)object2 title]];
    }
    if (NULL_OBJECT([(Book*)object1 fromSaga])) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if (NULL_OBJECT([(Book*)object2 fromSaga])) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return [super compareObject:[(Book*)object1 tomaison] toObject:[(Book*)object1 tomaison]];
}
```

Any idea what I can and should do ?

Thanks !

EDIT: there was a type in the last line

Comment: Is this part of an NSFetchRequest? What Core Data backing store are you using? If it's an SQL backend, you can't use code-based sort descriptors with an NSFetchRequest.

Comment: It is indeed part of an NSFetchRequest and I'm using a standard CoreData model (.xcdatamodel, NSManagedObjectContext, etc.). Note that the second sort descriptor works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using an SQL-based store, you could do this by passing self as your key and compare: as the selector, then implement that custom selector. That is, make a method on your book class called compare: and just have it do all of your logic rather than using multiple sort descriptors.

Comment: This is interesting. However, it doesn't seem to work either. I have implemented a custom selector in my Book class (in a category to be more specific) and it crashed. I've verified with some very simple test: 

`- (NSComparisonResult)specialCompare:(id)other { return NSOrderedSame; }`

And in the ViewController: 

`NSSortDescriptor* thirdSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES selector:@selector(specialCompare:)];`

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Additional note: I can't simply override the compare: method in Book.h as this is not the only place where I compare two Books, and the other places have other sorting methods

Comment: That looks OK to me. Where does the crash happen? What message do you get?

Comment: The crash happens during the `[theFetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];` call. No message, unfortunately it's not possible to debug (or at least, not of my knowledge), log or anything in a custom NSSortDescriptor.

Comment: Are you using an SQLLite-based backing store? If so, you should fetch them (unsorted) and then sort the resulting array yourself.

Comment: It will need some refactoring (I was using a NSFetchedResultController instead of just the results) but it seems to be working. Thanks :)